# get list of category without hard refresh in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i have an app in which i can view the list of products under category, each time i click the category to view a product it won't display until i hard refresh my browser before i get to display the list under the category

this is how i display the list of category in my navbar

```
<div
            class="pt-4 p-3"
            v-for="category in categories"
            :key="category._id"
          >
            <router-link :to="`/categories/${category._id}`">
              {{ category.type }}
            </router-link>
          </div>
```

this is my script tag to display the list of products the category.ID

```
<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "Product",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      category: {},
      categories: [],
      products: [],
      catID: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get(`https://taad.herokuapp.com/api/categories/${this.$route.params.id}`, {})
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.category = response.data.category;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        error;
      });

    axios
      .get(`https://td.herokuapp.com/api/products`, {})
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);

        this.products = response.data.products;
        const catID = this.category._id;
        this.products = this.products.filter(
          ({ category }) => catID === category._id
        );
      })
      .catch(error => {
        error;
      });
    axios.get("https://td.herokuapp.com/api/categories").then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.categories = res.data.categories;
    });
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["addProductToCart"]),
    logout() {
      localStorage.clear();
      this.$router.push("/login");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

if i click the a category from the navbar it takes me to the category.ID and display the product , but clicking another category when i'm on category.id page it changes the category.ID in my browser url , but wont update the product until i hard refresh it before it displays the product.

please what i'm i doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to use `beforeRouteUpdate` and call the `axios` part again.

From the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#using-the-options-api)

```
  beforeRouteUpdate(to, from) {
    // called when the route that renders this component has changed, but this component is reused in the new route.
    // For example, given a route with params `/users/:id`, when we navigate between `/users/1` and `/users/2`,
    // the same `UserDetails` component instance will be reused, and this hook will be called when that happens.
    // Because the component is mounted while this happens, the navigation guard has access to `this` component instance.
  },
```